# .php .htaccess rewrite on a homestead/laravel project

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, url-rewriting, homestead

I've read many tutorials on rewriting the /page.php to /page but I cannot get this to work on my laravel website..

```
# do not allow anyone else to read your .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The url doesn't rewrite using this content in the .htaccess file. Am I making a schoolboy error?

In fact, the page never really finishes loading!

Comment: Why you don't create route and controller and add in controler your page.php stuff

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start with adding a controller @Buglinjo. I appreciate your help advice with this though!

I created my business website using php files as includes such as header.php and partials/testimonials.php

Comment: You should look into [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I think I've sorted it